# Entity Foreign Keys in GridViews

Tags: entity-framework

Has anyone been able to find a clean solution to display a foreign key value in a GridView using an EntityDataSource?

For example, my Employees table has a (FK)JobTitleID and I want the Employees GridView to display a Job Title column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use bind the value to an TemplateField. Inside you can use whatever type of Bind control that is suitable for you type of data. Here is an example:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvEmployees" runat="server" AllowSorting="true" AutoGenerateColumns="false" DataKeyNames="ID" DataSourceID="godsCourses">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Job Title">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Literal ID="hlProgram" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("JobTitle.Name") %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

I have used `JobTitle.Name` supposing that the `JobTitleID` is connected to `JobTitle` entity.

Comment: Unfortunately I can not test this at my current site, but I will mark it as the correct answer based on the comment above.

Answer (score 2):

I tried this and it didn't work directly as advertised. You also need to ensure that the related tables are referenced in the Include property of the EntityDataSource. I couldn't see any way to control this in the EntityDataSorce 'Configure Data Source' wizard, so I entered it by hand in the HTML.

More info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.entitydatasource.include.aspx) in the MSDN documentation.

PS. I've read elsewhere that you have to use Eval but I seem to be able to use Eval or Bind interchangeably.