# How to display with Entity Framework value of a foreign key

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, telerik, telerik-grid

I'm working on a grid where I want show not the value of the connected foreign key but it should not look like (`1,2,3,57` etc) that is already working ... I want to show really the value behind the numbers like (`test,lead,foo,bar` etc..) I think that should be possible

I'm using Entity Framework 5.0 with asp.net 4.5

My `EntityDataSource`:

```
<asp:EntityDataSource ID="EntityDataSource1" runat="server" 
     ConnectionString="name=zevtestEntities" DefaultContainerName="zevtestEntities" 
     EnableFlattening="False" EntitySetName="BU"></asp:EntityDataSource>
```

I have already tried:

```
<telerik:GridBoundColumn
    DataField="ZevUser.FirstName" FilterControlAltText="Filter Creator column"
    HeaderText="Creator" ItemStyle-Width="60px" SortExpression="Creator" UniqueName="Creator">
    <ItemStyle Width="60px" />
</telerik:GridBoundColumn>
```

And `ZevUser` is the source table where the values are stored as text, is there another way to do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Entity Foreign Keys in GridViews](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1255935/entity-foreign-keys-in-gridviews)

Answer (score 4):

You almost have it.  You can reference the related entity in EF using the include property in your EntityDataSource.  Try Include="ZevUser" after your EntitySetName.  See the below link for more information.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.entitydatasource.include.aspx